# Node : Get all day in a week for the same month

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

Using NodeJS I currently struggle with a date issue.
I need to get the first and last day of a week only if they are in the same month.
And this for the on-going week.
For example, for this week, I want it to return `20` (Monday) and `24` (Friday) -> in my timezone.

The issue is when two months are on the same week.

Example : We had Mon 27 feb / Tue 28 Feb / Wed 1 Mar

I need to get `27 / 28` when we are on monday and tuesday,
And `1 / 3` when we are on Wednesday Thursday and Friday
(According to the previous example)

Currently I have this :

```js
  const date = new Date();

  const startOfWeek = new Date(date);
  startOfWeek.setDate(startOfWeek.getDate() - startOfWeek.getDay() + 1);
  const firstDay = startOfWeek.getDate();

  const endOfWeek = new Date(date);
  endOfWeek.setDate(endOfWeek.getDate() + (5 - endOfWeek.getDay()));
  const lastDay = endOfWeek.getDate();
```

It works to get all date for the current week but when there are two months, firstDay is in the previous month and lastDay in the next month.

I tried searching for answers but I couldn't manage to get one for this case ...

Thanks !

Comment: It is a bit hard to explain. But I need to stop before the new month. For Tuesday 28th I need to see something like [27 , 28] and not [27, 28 ,1 , 2 , 3] (The "array" is an example, I just the the first and the last)

And on Friday I want to have something like [1, 2 ,3]

Comment: Given you already know *startOfWeek*, then *endOfWeek* is just `let endOfWeek = new Date(startOfWeek.getFullYear(), startOfWeek.getMonth(), startOfWeek.getDate() + 5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you've clarified:

> It is a bit hard to explain. But I need to stop before the new month. For Tuesday 28th I need to see something like [27 , 28] and not [27, 28 ,1 , 2 , 3] (The "array" is an example, I just the the first and the las

In that case, make note of the month of `startOfWeek` and only step forward as long as the month doesn't change:

```
const startOfWeek = new Date(date);
startOfWeek.setDate(startOfWeek.getDate() - startOfWeek.getDay() + 1);

const days = [];
const startMonth = startOfWeek.getMonth();
const dt = new Date(startOfWeek);
while (days.length < 5) {
    days.push(dt.getDate());
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    if (dt.getMonth() !== startMonth) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function test(date) {
    const startOfWeek = new Date(date);
    startOfWeek.setDate(startOfWeek.getDate() - startOfWeek.getDay() + 1);

    const days = [];
    const startMonth = startOfWeek.getMonth();
    const dt = new Date(startOfWeek);
    while (days.length < 5) {
        days.push(dt.getDate());
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        if (dt.getMonth() !== startMonth) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(`Date: ${date}`);
    console.log(`Days: ${JSON.stringify(days)}`);
}

console.log("Starting today");
test(new Date());

console.log("Starting 2023-02-28");
test(new Date("2023-02-28"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked ! Just added a way to have dt to be the first day of ongoing month and I could manage to get what I want ! Thank you for your answer !